# QSqldriver not loaded, but available

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a program in Qt and I have a little problem. This compiles fine, but I have this:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

When I use `ldd libqsqlmysql.so` in `/opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers`, I get this:

```
./libqsqlmysql.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16: version `libmysqlclient_16' not found (required by ./libqsqlmysql.so)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe02bb3000)
libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (0x00007fa3f8431000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa3f8217000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fa3f7fde000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fa3f7dc4000)
libssl.so.10 => not found
libcrypto.so.10 => not found
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007fa3f7b83000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fa3f743d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa3f721e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa3f6e9c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa3f6b94000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa3f697c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa3f65b2000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa3f63ae000)
libicui18n.so.54 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicui18n.so.54 (0x00007fa3f5f3f000)
libicuuc.so.54 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicuuc.so.54 (0x00007fa3f5b91000)
libicudata.so.54 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicudata.so.54 (0x00007fa3f4166000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa3f3f64000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa3f3d5c000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa3f3a4d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558b780a6000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa3f37df000)
```

My code:

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("hostname");
db.setDatabaseName("name");
db.setUserName("username");
db.setPassword("password");
```

What is the problem?

Edit: I tried install openssl, but when I wrote `sudo apt-get install openssl` I got this:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version.
openssl set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-pl libdlrestrictions1 libkdecore5
  linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.2.0-18
  linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic linux-headers-4.2.0-19
  linux-headers-4.2.0-19-generic linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-18-generic linux-image-4.2.0-19-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-18-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-19-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.2.0-18-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-19-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Next edit: ok,I again use ldd libqmysql.so and i got this:

```
./libqsqlmysql.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16: version `libmysqlclient_16' not found (required by ./libqsqlmysql.so)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdb25e9000)
libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (0x00007f54d5b3f000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f54d5925000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f54d56ec000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f54d54d2000)
libssl.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f54d5269000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f54d4e26000)
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f54d4be6000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f54d44a0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f54d4281000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f54d3eff000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f54d3bf7000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f54d39df000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f54d3615000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f54d3411000)
libicui18n.so.54 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicui18n.so.54 (0x00007f54d2fa2000)
libicuuc.so.54 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicuuc.so.54 (0x00007f54d2bf4000)
libicudata.so.54 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicudata.so.54 (0x00007f54d11c9000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f54d0fc7000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f54d0dbf000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f54d0aaf000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d80d1dc000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f54d0842000)
```

Comment: Regarding your rollback: the trailing sentences are unnecessary noise, not contributing essential information to the question. And as it stands, your question is grammatically fine and understandable.

Comment: `libssl.so.10 => not found` and `libcrypto.so.10 => not found`  install openssl to your system and try again

Comment: @mcjulcz44 How did you install library for mysql client? I see this error `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16: version 'libmysqlclient_16' not found (required by ./libqsqlmysql.so)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

And, also inform your Qt distributor to change the linker.

**NOTE**

The problem was that there is an incompatibility between Qt and your `libmysqlclient`. Right now, we can only install the `libmysqlclient18` via

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient18
```

And it won't compatibility with your Qt installation because it requires version 16.

I would recommend you to upgrade your Qt installation

Comment: Does it work or not? Inform them where you downloaded this Qt binary

Comment: QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Comment: I mean can you ldd libqmysql again to find missing library

Comment: @mcjulcz44 How did you install library for mysql client? I see this error `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16: version 'libmysqlclient_16' not found (required by ./libqsqlmysql.so)`

Comment: Qt install this, when I install Qt Creator :/

Comment: It seems like a bug with `libmysqlclient` see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60061 Try `apt-get install --reinstall libmysqlclient` If it doesn't work, try to uninstall it, then install libmysqlclient16

Comment: When I tried: sudo apt-get install --reinstall libmysqlclient - I got this:
[sudo] password for mcjulcz: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient

Comment: When I tried sudo apt-get remove libmysqlclient - I got this:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient

Comment: When I tried sudo apt-get remove libmysqlclient - I get this:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient

Comment: It's `libmysqlclient18` now, I would recommend you to upgrade your Qt installation or build Qt from source.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and some Google research and intuition finally solved it.
Using Qt5.9.1 and Ubuntu 17.10

First, check if the error of `libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found` is present

```
    :~/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$ ldd libqsqlmysql.so
```

Second, search where is libmysqlclient

```
    :/$ locate libmysqlclient
```

Third, go to the folder where libmysqlclient is present and there make the link

```
    :/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ sudo ln -s libmysqlclient.so.20 libmysqlclient.so.18
```

and check the link made before with

```
    ls -alh | grep libmysql
```

At that moment, none of those solved for me, and i decided to look further in synaptic packages, and realize that `libqt5sql5-mysql` version 5.9.1 was not installed, so installing it solved the problem but i still have a message when doing ldd

> ./libqsqlmysql.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18: version `libmysqlclient_18' not found (required by ./libqsqlmysql.so)

after that, found some links that guide me to a real solution, here are them, if you wanna know whats happening

i downloaded the library stated in the third link and worked like a charm. hope it helps!

https://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/107611-difference-between-libsqlclient-so-libsqlclient_r-so.html

http://www.tango-controls.org/community/forum/c/general/installation/ubuntu-1604-problem-installing-from-source-code-libmysqlclient-replaces-libmysqlclient_r/

https://superuser.com/questions/1101426/installing-libmysqlclient18-on-ubuntu-16-04?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa&newreg=9c558283c488461aaf597ef1132e4ca0